# What comes between Angel #15 and Angel #16?

Tags: comics, buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

The original Dark Horse *Angel* and *Buffy* comics (i.e. the ones set during the TV shows, not the ones that take place afterwards) are being released in digital form.

[*Angel* #15](https://digital.darkhorse.com/profile/1146.angel-15/), "Part One of Past Lives", is a *Buffy* crossover.  [*Angel* #16](https://digital.darkhorse.com/profile/1147.angel-16/) is "Part Three of Past Lives", and says (on page two):

> continued from *Buffy* #29

However, [*Buffy the Vampire Slayer: Classic* #29](https://digital.darkhorse.com/profile/1365.buffy-the-vampire-slayer-classic-29-haunted/) is "Haunted", not any part of "Past Lives".

I'm guessing that the numbering of the *Buffy Classic* doesn't match the original numbering (which is what the *Angel* reference is to).

Which (digital) issue of *Buffy* does contain the middle part of the "Past Lives" storyline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently none of the digital issues have the rest of the storyline.  A quick search for "Past Lives" on Dark Horse's site only shows the two issues of Angel and [this TPB](http://www.darkhorse.com/Books/11-195/Buffy-the-Vampire-Slayer-Vol-8-Past-Lives-TPB) of Buffy.

When [asked](https://digital.darkhorse.com/contact/), Amber at Dark Horse Digital said:

> The Buffy Classics that we are releasing digitally are the story-arcs from the Omnibuses, so they do not match up with the original single issues release numbers. However, the story titles are the same as those found on the single issues, which should (hopefully) help when trying to match up stories between print and digital.
>
> The single issue *Buffy the Vampire Slayer #29* was part of the Angel/Buffy cross-over story "Past Lives." The entire story-arc (from both Angel and Buffy issues) will be released in our digital store as *Buffy the Vampire Slayer Classic #38*. This is currently set for release in mid-April.

Comment: This probably seems rather foolish, but I never considered that one could search by issue title rather than just the series or creator...

Comment: @TonyMeyer Not foolish at all.  I just took a guess because Dark Horse's search engine is fairly horrible.  Searching just for "Buffy the Vampire Slayer #29" got 373 hits.

Comment: It took a while for them to get back to me, but they finally did, and confirmed that this is indeed correct.  Thanks!